# How to extend a 2x6 joist to accommodate a hanger board for stairs?

Tags: framing, stairs, construction, support

I live in an antique home with 2x6 ceiling joists. The stairs are being rebuilt and  the current hanger board for the stringers will not work. So I have attached a picture of the current setup and one of my idea to extend the joist down using a 2x12 and strong ties securing it to two adjacent 4x4 posts. Please let me know your thoughts on the strength of this design. Or any improvements or different ways to extend it down.

There is only about 2 inches behind the joist and posts to accommodate anything do to a finished room and basement stairway. This is why I've taken a minimalist approach.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume the opening for the stairs is on the far side of the picture.

I'd skip the ties and use 2x12 hangers on the posts.  If you have this area open you might want to tie the 2x6 joists to the 4x4 posts using ties for seismic/wind though.

Why does the current board not work?

Comment: Yes, the opening is on the far side. The current board isn't large enough to accommodate the large hanger board. The new stringers are very deep. And I cannot attach the hanger board to the front of the posts because it has to be flush with the 2x6 joist to keep the position of the stairs the same as they are currently. Also that will take away much needed, and valuable tread depth.